# How to enable VIM mode for editing notebooks in jupyter-lab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm new to jupyter lab. In `settings` -> `text editor key map` it has a `vim` option which, when enabled, allows me to edit `.py` files with vim-style editor. However, this behavior does not carry over to `.ipynb` files. How can I enable this for all files edited in jupyter-lab (most importantly `.ipynb`)?

Internet search has revealed a plenty of vim addons for jupyter (mostly jupyter-notebook I believe), but since this behavior is already available out of the box for `.py`, I would assume this can be somehow configured without third-party addons. In any case, I will be grateful for information because what I find on the Internet seems to be mostly outdated/related to jupyter-notebook.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**jupyterlab 4.x**

`pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-vim >= 4.0.1`

`4.1.1` is the last version to support `jupyterlab < 4.1`

**jupyterlab 3.x**:

`pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-vim < 0.17.0`

**jupyterlab 2.x**:

`jupyter labextension install @axlair/jupyterlab_vim`

**jupyterlab 1.x**:

`jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_vim`

History:

The original extension was:
https://github.com/jwkvam/jupyterlab-vim

however it was never updated for jlab2.x so the community shifted to a fork: https://github.com/axelfahy/jupyterlab-vim which has subsequently moved to https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-vim

There is also an effort to vim this into jlab core. See: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/8592

Comment: If you're installing from within a conda environment, use: `conda install --channel=conda-forge jupyterlab_vim`